# python - Is my code ever reaching the proxy method? - requests

Tags: proxy, python-requests

So I am playing around with proxies here and there with requests, Basically meaning that if I run a proxy with a requests. It will then be used in the whole session with that requests. Now I have coded but I haven't been able to check if it really goes through and I don't either know if this place is correct to paste. What I have done is looking like

```
with open('proxies.json') as json_data_file:
    proxies = json.load(json_data_file)


def setProxy(proxy):
    s = requests.Session()

    proxies = {'http': 'http://' + proxy,
               'https': 'http://' + proxy}
    s.proxies.update(proxies)
    return s


def info(thread):
    global prod
    prod = int(thread) + 1
    runit(proxies)


def runit(proxies):
    try:
        if proxies != []:
            s = setProxy(random.choice(proxies))
            sleepy = time.sleep(.5)
        else:
            s = requests.Session()
            sleepy = time.sleep(1)

        r = s.get(url)


    except requests.exceptions.ProxyError:
        log(Fore.RED + "Proxy DEAD - rotating" + Fore.RESET)
        sleepy
        passwd(proxies)

 PostUrl = s.post('www.hellotest.com')
 print("Does it actually use the proxy or not?"

def main():

            i = 0
            jobs = []
            for i in range(10):
                p = multiprocessing.Process(target=info, args=(str(i),))
                jobs.append(p)
                time.sleep(.5)
                p.start()

            for p in jobs:
                p.join()

            sys.exit()
```

Is there a way to actually see if it does it or not? This is also my first time doing it so! Please do not judge!

Comment: Use `s.get('https://httpbin.org/get').json()['origin']` and if the IP address in that of the proxy, you'll know for certain. If the proxy sets additional headers, you'd find them in the `'headers'` key.

Comment: Oh awesome @MartijnPieters - Looks like it does work afterall! Thank you! :)